# no module named ecdsa with Paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko, ecdsa

I keep coming up with the error `no module named ecdsa` when I run a program with Paramiko. I have installed it using pip, and it says that it *has* installed, but when I run the program again, it comes up with the error again!

What can I do? I'm using Linux, by the way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure you have `ecdsa` module installed in your linux system. Go to prompt, and try running the following commands:

```
    mamun@bobolink:~$ python
    Python 2.7.5+ (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:37:08)
    [GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> from ecdsa import SigningKey
    >>> sk = SigningKey.generate() # uses NIST192p
    >>>
```

If you get error, then try installing the `ecdsa` module by the following command:

```
    mamun@bobolink:~$ sudo pip install ecdsa
```

And you will get the following output that would confirm that the package has been installed.

```
    Downloading/unpacking ecdsa
      Downloading ecdsa-0.11.tar.gz (45kB): 45kB downloaded
      Running setup.py egg_info for package ecdsa

    Installing collected packages: ecdsa
      Running setup.py install for ecdsa

    Successfully installed ecdsa
    Cleaning up...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Python 3.x you might have to use pip3 instead of pip:

```
sudo pip3 install ecdsa
```